# python -m unittest2 discover not working

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, unittest2, python-3.1

I'm using the excellent Tox tool to test my code. Here is my `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py26,py27,py31,py32,py33

[testenv]
deps = ParamUnittest
commands = python -m unittest discover tests
downloadcache = build

[testenv:py26]
deps = https://github.com/rik0/ParamUnittest/tarball/master
       unittest2
       importlib
commands = python -m unittest2.__main__ discover tests

[testenv:py31]
deps = https://github.com/rik0/ParamUnittest/tarball/master
       unittest2py3k
commands = python -m unittest2 discover tests
```

When running it all tests are executed on all versions except 3.1. Tox shows:

```
py31 sdist-reinst: /home/miki/exp/radon/.tox/dist/radon-0.1.zip
py31 runtests: commands[0]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why tests are not executed? System layout is as follows:

```
tests/
    test_internals.py
    test_complexity.py
    ...
radon/
...
setup.py
tox.ini
```

Comment: It's probably a bug, so I'll file one.